# How to place the two images in single canvas using asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, canvas

```
      function draw() 
      {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function()
         {
                ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(30,96);
                ctx.lineTo(70,66);
                ctx.lineTo(103,76);
                ctx.lineTo(170,15);
                ctx.stroke();
         };
        img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5395/backdrop.png';
      }
```

I have this function in this code two images are placing in canvas but within few sec second img is moving to other place.i want to place both img in canvas how to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, hope this help: 

### DEMO FIDDLE

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img1 = loadImage('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png', main);
var img2 = loadImage('http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/peppers.jpg', main);
var imagesLoaded = 0;
function main() {
    imagesLoaded += 1;

    if (imagesLoaded == 2) {
        // composite now
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
        ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
    }
}

function loadImage(src, onload) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = onload;
    img.src = src;
    return img;
}
```